Robot randomly sliding around in Gazebo
I'm using Gazebo Citadel alongside ROS 2 Foxy. For some reason once I load my URDF and controllers (ROS2 Control) into Gazebo, the robot (a quadruped with no wheels) randomly slides around.
Here is my URDF:
<!-- =================================================================================== -->
<!-- |    This document was autogenerated by xacro from /home/samee/ros2_ws/src/servo_controller/urdf/fixed_urdf2.urdf | -->
<!-- |    EDITING THIS FILE BY HAND IS NOT RECOMMENDED                                 | -->
<!-- =================================================================================== -->
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="robot">

  <!-- Gazebo plugin for ros2_control -->
  <gazebo>
    <plugin name="gazebo_ros2_control" filename="libgazebo_ros2_control.so">
      <parameters>/home/samee/ros2_ws/src/servo_controller/config/robot_controllers.yaml</parameters>

    </plugin>

  </gazebo>
<link name="base_footprint" />

<joint name="base_footprint_joint" type="fixed">
  <parent link="base_footprint" />
  <child link="base_link" />
</joint>
  <link name="base_link">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.254 0.127 0.0635"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.254 0.127 0.0635"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0.000 0.000 0.000" xyz="0.000 0.000 0.000"/>
      <mass value="2.000"/>
<inertia  ixx="0.0033602083333333335" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.011424708333333334" iyz="0" izz="0.013440833333333334" />   </inertial>
  </link>

  <!-- FL -->
  <joint name="hip_fl" type="revolute">
          <dynamics damping="0.7" friction="1.0"/>

    <limit effort="100" lower="-0.2" upper="0.4" velocity="10"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0508 0.0508 0"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="hipbone_fl"/>
    <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="hipbone_fl">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0 0.0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.0635 0.03175 0.0381"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0 0.0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.0635 0.03175 0.0381"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0.000 0.000 0.000" xyz="0.000 0.000 0.000"/>
      <mass value="0.233"/>
<inertia  ixx="4.775864104166667e-05" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.00010647828166666667" iyz="0" izz="9.786606770833334e-05" />    </inertial>
  </link>

  <joint name="shoulder_fl" type="revolute">
          <dynamics damping="0.7" friction="1.0"/>

    <limit effort="100" lower="-0.1" upper="0.6" velocity="10"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    <parent link="hipbone_fl"/>
    <child link="femur_fl"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="femur_fl">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0 0.027 -0.0635"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.0254 0.0254 0.127"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0 0.027 -0.0635"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.0254 0.0254 0.127"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0.000 0.000 0.000" xyz="0.0 0.027 -0.0635"/>
      <mass value="1"/>
<inertia  ixx="0.0013978466666666666" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.0013978466666666666" iyz="0" izz="0.00010752666666666665" />  </inertial>
  </link>

  <joint name="knee_fl" type="revolute">
      <dynamics damping="0.7" friction="1.0"/>

    <limit effort="100" lower="-0.5" upper="2" velocity="10"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 1.57" xyz="0 0 -0.127"/>
    <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
    <parent link="femur_fl"/>
    <child link="tibia_fl"/>
  </joint>
<gazebo reference="tibia_fl">
    <minDepth>0.005</minDepth>
    <mu1>150</mu1>
    <mu2>150</mu2>
    <material>Gazebo/Orange</material>
    <fdir1>1.0 0 0</fdir1>
</gazebo>
  <link name="tibia_fl">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0254 0.0 -0.06985"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.00635 0.00635 0.1397"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
            <contact_coefficients mu="1"/>

      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0254 0.0 -0.06985"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.00635 0.00635 0.1397"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0.000 0.000 0.000" xyz="0.0254 0.0 -0.06985"/>
      <mass value="1"/>
<inertia  ixx="0.001629701041666666" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.001629701041666666" iyz="0" izz="6.720416666666666e-06" />   </inertial>
  </link>

  <!-- FR -->
  <joint name="hip_fr" type="revolute">
          <dynamics damping="0.7" friction="1.0"/>

    <limit effort="100" lower="-0.2" upper="0.4" velocity="10"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 3.14" xyz="0.0508 -0.0508 0"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="hipbone_fr"/>
    <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="hipbone_fr">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz=" 0.0 0.0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.0635 0.03175 0.0381"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz=" 0.0 0.0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.0635 0.03175 0.0381"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0.000 0.000 0.000" xyz="0.000 0.000 0.000"/>
      <mass value="0.233"/>
<inertia  ixx="4.775864104166667e-05" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.00010647828166666667" iyz="0" izz="9.786606770833334e-05" />  </inertial>
  </link>

  <joint name="shoulder_fr" type="revolute">
          <dynamics damping="0.7" friction="1.0"/>

    <limit effort="100" lower="-0.6" upper="0.1" velocity="10"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    <parent link="hipbone_fr"/>
    <child link="femur_fr"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="femur_fr">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0 0.027 -0.0635"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.0254 0.0254 0.127"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0 0.027 -0.0635"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.0254 0.0254 0.127"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0.000 0.000 0.000" xyz="0.0 0.027 -0.0635"/>
      <mass value="1"/>
<inertia  ixx="0.0013978466666666666" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.0013978466666666666" iyz="0" izz="0.00010752666666666665" />  </inertial>
  </link>

  <joint name="knee_fr" type="revolute">
      <dynamics damping="0.7" friction="1.0"/>

    <limit effort="100" lower="-0.5" upper="2" velocity="10"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 1.57" xyz="0 0 -0.127"/>
    <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
    <parent link="femur_fr"/>
    <child link="tibia_fr"/>
  </joint>
<gazebo reference="tibia_fr">
    <minDepth>0.005</minDepth>
    <mu1>150</mu1>
    <mu2>150</mu2>
    <material>Gazebo/Orange</material>
    <fdir1>1.0 0 0</fdir1>
</gazebo>
  <link name="tibia_fr">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0254 0.0 -0.06985"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.00635 0.00635 0.1397"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
            <contact_coefficients mu="1"/>

      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0254 0.0 -0.06985"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.00635 0.00635 0.1397"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0.000 0.000 0.000" xyz="0.0254 0.0 -0.06985"/>
      <mass value="1"/>
<inertia  ixx="0.001629701041666666" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.001629701041666666" iyz="0" izz="6.720416666666666e-06" />   </inertial>
  </link>

  <!-- BR -->
  <joint name="hip_br" type="revolute">
          <dynamics damping="0.7" friction="1.0"/>

    <limit effort="100" lower="-0.2" upper="0.4" velocity="10"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 3.14" xyz="-0.0508 -0.0508 0"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="hipbone_br"/>
    <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="hipbone_br">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz=" 0.0 0.0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.0635 0.03175 0.0381"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz=" 0.0 0.0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.0635 0.03175 0.0381"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0.000 0.000 0.000" xyz="0.000 0.000 0.000"/>
      <mass value="0.233"/>
<inertia  ixx="4.775864104166667e-05" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.00010647828166666667" iyz="0" izz="9.786606770833334e-05" />   </inertial>
  </link>

  <joint name="shoulder_br" type="revolute">
          <dynamics damping="0.7" friction="1.0"/>

    <limit effort="100" lower="-0.6" upper="0.1" velocity="10"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    <parent link="hipbone_br"/>
    <child link="femur_br"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="femur_br">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0 0.027 -0.0635"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.0254 0.0254 0.127"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0 0.027 -0.0635"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.0254 0.0254 0.127"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0.000 0.000 0.000" xyz="0.0 0.027 -0.0635"/>
      <mass value="1"/>
<inertia  ixx="0.0013978466666666666" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.0013978466666666666" iyz="0" izz="0.00010752666666666665" />  </inertial>
  </link>

  <joint name="knee_br" type="revolute">
      <dynamics damping="0.7" friction="1.0"/>

    <limit effort="100" lower="-0.5" upper="2" velocity="10"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 1.57" xyz="0 0 -0.127"/>
    <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
    <parent link="femur_br"/>
    <child link="tibia_br"/>
  </joint>
<gazebo reference="tibia_br">
    <minDepth>0.005</minDepth>
    <mu1>150</mu1>
    <mu2>150</mu2>
    <material>Gazebo/Orange</material>
    <fdir1>1.0 0 0</fdir1>
</gazebo>
  <link name="tibia_br">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0254 0.0 -0.06985"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.00635 0.00635 0.1397"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
            <contact_coefficients mu="1"/>

      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0254 0.0 -0.06985"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.00635 0.00635 0.1397"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0.000 0.000 0.000" xyz="0.0254 0.0 -0.06985"/>
      <mass value="1"/>
<inertia  ixx="0.001629701041666666" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.001629701041666666" iyz="0" izz="6.720416666666666e-06" />  </inertial>
  </link>

  <!-- BL -->
  <joint name="hip_bl" type="revolute">
          <dynamics damping="0.7" friction="1.0"/>

    <limit effort="100" lower="-0.2" upper="0.4" velocity="10"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.0508 0.0508 0"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="hipbone_bl"/>
    <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="hipbone_bl">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz=" 0.0 0.0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.0635 0.03175 0.0381"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz=" 0.0 0.0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.0635 0.03175 0.0381"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0.000 0.000 0.000" xyz="0.000 0.000 0.000"/>
      <mass value="0.233"/>
<inertia  ixx="4.775864104166667e-05" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.00010647828166666667" iyz="0" izz="9.786606770833334e-05" />   </inertial>
  </link>

  <joint name="shoulder_bl" type="revolute">
          <dynamics damping="0.7" friction="1.0"/>

    <limit effort="100" lower="-0.1" upper="0.6" velocity="10"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    <parent link="hipbone_bl"/>
    <child link="femur_bl"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="femur_bl">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0 0.027 -0.0635"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.0254 0.0254 0.127"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0 0.027 -0.0635"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.0254 0.0254 0.127"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0.000 0.000 0.000" xyz="0.0 0.027 -0.0635"/>
      <mass value="1"/>
<inertia  ixx="0.0013978466666666666" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.0013978466666666666" iyz="0" izz="0.00010752666666666665" /> </inertial>
  </link>

  <joint name="knee_bl" type="revolute">
      <dynamics damping="0.7" friction="1.0"/>

    <limit effort="100" lower="-0.5" upper="2" velocity="10"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 1.57" xyz="0 0 -0.127"/>
    <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
    <parent link="femur_bl"/>
    <child link="tibia_bl"/>
  </joint>
<gazebo reference="tibia_bl">
    <minDepth>0.005</minDepth>
    <mu1>150</mu1>
    <mu2>150</mu2>
    <material>Gazebo/Orange</material>
    <fdir1>1.0 0 0</fdir1>
</gazebo>
  <link name="tibia_bl">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0254 0.0 -0.06985"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.00635 0.00635 0.1397"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <contact_coefficients mu="1"/>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0254 0.0 -0.06985"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.00635 0.00635 0.1397"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0.000 0.000 0.000" xyz="0.0254 0.0 -0.06985"/>
      <mass value="1"/>
<inertia  ixx="0.001629701041666666" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.001629701041666666" iyz="0" izz="6.720416666666666e-06" />  </inertial>
  </link>

  <!-- ros2_control Configuration -->
  <ros2_control name="GazeboSystem" type="system">
    <hardware>
      <plugin>gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem</plugin>

    </hardware>

    <!-- Define all the joints that will be controlled -->
    <joint name="hip_fl">
      <state_interface name="position"/>
      <command_interface name="position"/>
    </joint>

    <joint name="shoulder_fl">
      <state_interface name="position"/>
      <command_interface name="position"/>
    </joint>

    <joint name="knee_fl">
      <state_interface name="position"/>
      <command_interface name="position"/>
    </joint>

    <joint name="hip_fr">
      <state_interface name="position"/>
      <command_interface name="position"/>
    </joint>

    <joint name="shoulder_fr">
      <state_interface name="position"/>
      <command_interface name="position"/>
    </joint>

    <joint name="knee_fr">
      <state_interface name="position"/>
      <command_interface name="position"/>
    </joint>

    <joint name="hip_br">
      <state_interface name="position"/>
      <command_interface name="position"/>
    </joint>

    <joint name="shoulder_br">
      <state_interface name="position"/>
      <command_interface name="position"/>
    </joint>

    <joint name="knee_br">
      <state_interface name="position"/>
      <command_interface name="position"/>
    </joint>

    <joint name="hip_bl">
      <state_interface name="position"/>
      <command_interface name="position"/>
    </joint>

    <joint name="shoulder_bl">
      <state_interface name="position"/>
      <command_interface name="position"/>
    </joint>

    <joint name="knee_bl">
      <state_interface name="position"/>
      <command_interface name="position"/>
    </joint>

  </ros2_control>

  <!-- <xacro:include filename="example_gazebo.xacro" /> -->

</robot>

robot_controllers.yaml:
controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 100  # Hz
    use_sim_time: true

    joint_trajectory_controller:
      type: joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController

    joint_state_broadcaster:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster

    position_controllers:
      type: position_controllers/JointGroupPositionController


position_controllers:
  ros__parameters:
    type: position_controllers/JointGroupPositionController
    joints:
      - hip_fl
      - shoulder_fl
      - knee_fl
      - hip_fr
      - shoulder_fr
      - knee_fr
      - hip_bl
      - shoulder_bl
      - knee_bl
      - hip_br
      - shoulder_br
      - knee_br
    command_interfaces:
      - position
    state_interfaces:
      - position

Here is a GIF of the robot and its behavior:
Here is an image of the robot in Gazebo with "Show Inertias" ticked:

As you can see, the inertia boxes line up perfectly with the robot's parts. What can I do to solve this issue?

I seem to have solved the problem by upgrading to ROS2 Jazzy. There is some work required to change the names of packages, etc when using launch files but it seems to solve the issue. When gazebo is loaded, the robot loads in as usual and when the initial positions are published, it reacts as expected.
